Integration of a differential form pullback
Consider the usual definition of the pullback of a differential form:
$$f^*\omega(p)(v_1,v_2,...,v_k)=\omega_{f(p)}(Df_p(v_1),Df_p(v_2),...,Df_p(v_k))$$
where $f:U\subset \mathbb R^n\to V\subset \mathbb R^m$ is an orientation-preserving diffemorphism, $\omega\in \Omega^k(V)$ a $k-$form on $V$, $p$ a point in $U$ ($p \in U$), $v_1, ... v_k$ a set of tangent vectors at $p$, $Df(v_n)$ the pushforward of $v_n$ through $f$. Let also $q$ be a point of $V$.
Since $f$ is an orientation-preserving diffeomorphism, its Jacobian determinant at every point $p$ of $U$ is positive. Let $J_f(p)$ denote the Jacobian determinant of $f$ at the point $p$. Then, thanks to the change of variables formula for integration, we have:
$$\int_U f^*\omega(p)(v_1,v_2,...,v_k)= \int_U \omega_{f(p)}(Df_p(v_1),Df_p(v_2),...,Df_p(v_k)) J_f(p)$$
I've read that "making the identification $q=f(p)$" it is possible to rewrite the former integral as:
$$\int_U f^*\omega(p)(v_1,v_2,...,v_k)= \int_V \omega_q(v_1, v_2,..., v_k)$$
My questions are:

is this reasoning legit?
in $\int_V \omega_q(v_1, v_2,..., v_k)$, are in fact $v_1, ... v_k$ the original vectors of the tangent space at $p$ (and so $\omega_q$ operates on the original vectors at $p \in U$) or are some pushforwarded vectors at $q \in V$?


Where have you read all this, in particular what leads to that last formula? It is true that a differential form takes a point $p$ as argument and eats vectors $v_i,.$ But then this becomes a number which we can't use to integrate over $U,.$ The standard notation is $\int_Uf^*\omega=\int_V\omega,.$ I suggest to practice a few concrete examples. It boils down to chain rule and integral transformation fomula.

@KurtG. I've taken the essential part from here: https://www.vaia.com/en-us/textbooks/physics/mathematical-methods-of-classical-mechanics-2-edition/chapter-7/problem-44-let-d1-and-d2-be-two-compact-convex-polyhedra-in-/

@KurtG. in fact it's a proposed solution for Problem 6 at page 183 of Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics by V. I. Arnol'd

This proposed solution (which is obviously not by Arnold) looks weird. Those integrals should not depend on $p$ and on $v_i,.$ Keep practising. You can even come up with your own concrete examples.

@KurtG. have you got an insight for the way to proceed? What do you mean by $\int_U f^*{\omega} = \int_V \omega$ "boils down to chain rule and integral transformation fomula", if that way of thinking is not valid?

Things like that. Evaluating a surface integral is done by pulling back a form to the set in $\mathbb R^2$ that is used to parametrize the region on the surface. The form is written in coordinates $dx,dy,dz$ and we pullback to $d\theta,d\varphi,.$

If $f$ is a diffeomorphisms, then, for starters, we must have $m=n$. And to define the integral, $k$ needs to be $m=n$. You are fixing $n$ vectors and then integrating what? A function. But we only know how to integrate actual differential $k$-forms over $k$-dimensional manifolds. So you are implicitly fixing volume elements on $U$ and $V$? Arnol'd does not write what you're writing, of course. But he is integrating a $k$-form over a $k$-dimensional polyhedron. (You might find some of my YouTube lectures, linked in my profile, of help.)

@TedShifrin thank you but it's a bit generic and I couldn't follow you...I'm using the same k-form used by Arnol'd in his Problem...
